# Javascript Looping syntax

Tags: javascript, loops, syntax, for-loop

This should be easy for someone, I just can't seem to get the syntax correct. I have the following code, and I'm sure 70% of this can be represented by a loop: could someone enlighten me please?

```
function AddNewEmail(){
var jFilesContainer = $( "#emails" );
var jUploadTemplate = $( "#email-templates div.template" );
var jUpload = jUploadTemplate.clone(); 
var strNewHTML = jUpload.html();
var intNewFileCount = (jFilesContainer.find( "div.template" ).length + 1); 
jUpload.attr( "id", ("emailedit[" + intNewFileCount + "]") );
strNewHTML = strNewHTML
    .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD1::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
            .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD2::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
            .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD3::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD4::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD5::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD6::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD7::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD8::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD9::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD10::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        )
                .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD11::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        ) 
            .replace(
        new RegExp( "::FIELD12::", "i" ),
        intNewFileCount
        ) 

;

jUpload.html( strNewHTML );
jFilesContainer.append( jUpload );
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using regular expressions, use them:

```
strNewHTML = strNewHTML.replace(/::FIELD\d{1,2}::/gi, intNewFileCount);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say

```
strNewHTML = strNewHTML.replace(/::FIELD\d+::/gi, intNewFileCount);
```

could be a replacement for your whole strNewHTML logic. Not a loop, but shorter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_loop_for.asp